# How do I vertically center an image within a panel in Step Carousel?

Tags: image, panel, center, carousel

HOw do I vertically center an image within a panel in Step Carousel?

Can I input a command into the following:

```
<div class="panel">

<a href="url" target="_blank">
<img src="/image" border="0" position= "center" alt="copy goes here" />
</a>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/XVMzf/1/

```
.panel { 
    vertical-align:middle; /* this is the key */
    display:table-cell; /* this is the key */
    height:400px; 
    width:600px; 
    text-align:center; 
    background-color:yellow; 

}

<div class="panel">
    <a href="url" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff&text=dummy-image" alt="copy goes here" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This is supported in all modern browsers, IE8 and up.

---

This will work in older browsers but you have to know the height of your .panel
http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/XVMzf/2/

Comment: What if each panel is of varying heights? I would like to center the midpoint of all my images so that everything remains in one line horizontally

Answer (score 0):

```
#Content-innerCt {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Try out this. It worked for me.